# all Unity project gives empty c# compiler errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was trying to configure plastic SCM for Unity when Unity projects on my computer suddenly started to give 2 empty compiler errors, with no useful debug info:

Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.9.1.65535 (9d34608e)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

[image: snapshot of errors]

From the editor log it looks like the UnityEngine.UI.dll and UnityEngine.TestRunner.dll failed to compile and error outputs in the log file are unreadable:

```
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.9.1.65535 (9d34608e)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
-----CompilerOutput:-stderr----------
ϵͳ�Ҳ���ָ����·����
-----EndCompilerOutput---------------
```

New projects created through Unity Hub has the same problem, and it appears in new projects of all versions of Unity I have(2020.3.10f1c1, 2019.4.10f1, 2018.4.13c1) (The only difference is that they logs a different version number of the compiler). My OS is Windows 10.

I've tried re-installing unity(2019.4.10f1), unity hub, visual studio (17 & 19) and .NET component in VS but the problem remains.

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This maybe can help you, some solutions are given, maybe they concern your case. Have you tried to google the error?:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/microsoft-r-visual-c-compiler-version-2-9-1-65535-9d34608e-copyright-c-microsoft-corporation.668395/

Comment: Many thanks! Deleting registry key really helped solved the problem. My `AutoRun` key pointed to a weird path(perhaps due to my previous projects). I've searched for solutions and seen similar answers though, but I'm not so familiar with registries. Also I tended to believe that the problem was caused by updating things since my Unity used to work properly. Anyway thanks for your suggestion.